# States visibility in type select and radio in drupal 7

Tags: 7, forms

I have a custom form

```
$form['basic']['legal_form'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => array(
    'option1' => 'option1',
    'option2' => 'option2',
    'option3' => 'option3',
  ),
  '#title' => 'My Dropdown',
);
//radio button to show if selected option3
$form['basic']['bearer_shares'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => 'Radio Button to show',
  '#options' => array(1 => t('yes'), 2 => t('no')),
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="legal_form"]' => array('value' => 'option3'),
    ),
  ),
);
```

I try too

```
':input[name="legal_form"]' => array('selected' => 'option3'),
```

If I change type to textfield it works as expected but not when I try to use radio. Can anyone suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: which Drupal core version are you using?

Comment: @jmu I am using Drupal 7.54.

Comment: I am not sure why your textfield worked before, cause I tried your code and it doesn't work like you said. Once I change `':input[name="legal_form"]' => array('value' => 'option3'),` to `':input[name="basic[legal_form]"]' => array('value' => 'option3'),` everything works. If my idea works, I can write as an answer after you confirm

Comment: Sorry is still not working @jmu

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$form['basic']['legal_form'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => array(
    'option1' => 'option1',
    'option2' => 'option2',
    'option3' => 'option3',
  ),
  '#title' => 'My Dropdown',
  '#attributes' => array('id' => 'selection_id'),
);

//radio button to show if selected option3
$form['basic']['bearer_shares'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => 'Radio Button to show',
  '#options' => array(1 => t('yes'), 2 => t('no')),
  '#states'           => array( 
    'visible' => array(
      'select[id="selection_id"]' => array('value' => 'option3')
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: It didn't work too.I did in java-script. Anyway,Thanks for your time.